# Check if dictionary value of key is null

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary

I try to use a Dictionary and need to Check if the Value of a Key (called Name) is empty and if so, then use some default string as Value for my Key as, something like "unknown".

I know I can check a string for example with `string.Length == 0` but my problem here is that I have an object as value and its hard for me to catch it.

Thats my code:

```
 IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 string Name = de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString(); //Name is sometimes empty and sometimes not
 parameters.Add("Name", Name);
```

Update:

```
IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string Name = de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
 if (parameters.TryGetValue("Name", out var Name))
    {
      parameters.Add("Name", Name ?? "unknown");
    }
```

Comment: `null` and empty, ie `""` are different things. An empty string has a value - it's empty. `null` means there's no value. You can check for both with [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `ContainsKey` method to check that `Name` key is exist in dictionary. Then get an actual string value by checking for `null` using [null-conditional `?.` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). If the result is `null` or empty string, you'll set the name to `unknown` value

```cs
if (de.Properties.ContainsKey("Name"))
{
    var name = de.Properties["Name"]?.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        name = "unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful in multi-thread situations: in between the check and the get the item could be removed by another thread. Use locking or a TryGetValue call

Answer (score 6):

`null` and an empty string are completely different things. `null` means there's no value, while an empty string *is* a string, it's just empty. You can't call `.ToString()` or `.Length` on a null, you'd get an exception precisely because there's no value to handle that call.

You can use [Dictionary.TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1) to check for existence and retrieve the value at the same time.

After that, if you really want to convert everything to a string, you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` to call `ToString()` without throwing if `name` is null. If `name` is null, the entire expression `name?.ToString()` evaluates to `null` too.

You can then use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` to replace nulls with a default value :

```
var de= new Dictionary<string, object?>();
de["Name1"]=null;
de["Name2"]=42;

if(de.TryGetValue("Name2",out var name))
{
    var valueAsString=name?.ToString() ;
    parameters.Add("Name2", valueAsString ?? "unknown");
}
```

If you just want to replace nulls with a default value, you don't need `ToString()` :

```
if(de.TryGetValue("Name2",out var name))
{
    parameters.Add("Name2", name ?? "unknown");
}
```

If you want to check for null or empty, you can use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
if(de.TryGetValue("Name2",out var name))
{
    var newValue=String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) 
                       ? "unknown" 
                       : name.ToString();  //Only if we want to format to strings
    parameters.Add("Name2", newValue);
}
```

Finally, if you want to *replace* existing keys in the `parameters` dictionary, use

```
parameters["Name2]= newValue;
```

Comment: @CodeCase that makes perfect sense if `Name` already exists. You didn't ask how to check the `parameters` dictionary though, you asked how to check `de`. If you want to *replace* or add, use `parameters["Name2"]=newValue`, not `Add`

Answer (score -2):

string result= (string)(YourDictionaryName.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? YourDictionaryName["YourParameterName"].ToString(): "");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).